# Adding values in two array with overlapping dimensions (outer join)

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have two xarrays with values along the same dimension. Some of the points overlap and some points along that dimension are only in the first or the second array. I would like to get a third array that adds the values and assumes 0 for missing values. I think this would be a sum of the two arrays along the dimension x doing an outer join. But I don't know how to do it.

```
import xarray as xr

x = xr.DataArray([1,2,3], dims=("x"), coords={"x": ['a', 'b', 'c']})
y = xr.DataArray([10,20,30], dims=("x"), coords={"x": ['b', 'c', 'd']})

x+y
```

In the example above I get a new array that only has two values 12 and 23 for points 'b' and 'c'. But what I would like is an array with four values 1, 12, 23, 30 for points 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'.

Comment: Use [`xarray.merge()`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.merge.html) with `join='outer'`

Comment: if you want to apply this behavior globally, you can use `xr.set_options(arithmetic_join="outer")`, but the missing value will be set to NaN by default, so you may have to map it afterwards
https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.set_options.html